# I want to populate arrayadapter each view into single frame layout

Tags: java, android, stack, kotlin, tinder

I trying to make a view that's look like tinder cardsteck view
And I thought how to populate each view in frame layout 
And each view stecked 
I don't get idea so far
And I don't want to use Library
NOTE - I'm not talking about ListView

Comment: You can definitely do this, but managing all the touch handling events and custom animations and thresholds of reaction as well as determine which view gets what touch at what time is opening a giant can of worms. You will dedicate a tremendous amount of time to getting this just right and upkeeping it. There are at least 3 libraries out there that already do this very well. I know you don't want to use a library, but unless you have a ton of time and energy, I wouldn't reinvent that wheel.

Comment: Brother touch events and other stuff I can manage it but man thing is how to populate all my card view in a single screen (I mean stack) I don't know how to do that please someone help me.

Comment: Why not just review a library that does it for code help then if you want to write your own? https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards for example, but obviously don't copy and paste the code, but it should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a Long Time, I Did that. 
I Don't Know how to put Dynamic View in Frame Layout(ViewGroup)
so I Used BaseAdapter and getView Through ForLoop and My work is done.
Thank you, Everybody, for Helping me.